# CSS: Show ordered list item index in a child element

Tags: html, css

I'm building an accordion type widget as in the following image:

[image: Accordion]

I'd like to use an ordered list where each `<li>` element contains a question, answer and expand/collapse button.

```
<li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
</li>
```

How do I display the list item index inside a child element of that list item without using Javascript? i.e. I want the `<span class="question">` element to show its parent's index as in `1. Example question`.

Comment: `li { list-style-type:decimal; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**CSS Counters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  counter-reset: li-count;
}

li {
  counter-increment: li-count;
}

li .question:before {
  content: counter( li-count) '. ';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question one.</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer one.</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question two.</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer two.</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiick

Comment: I don't really see a point of using `counter-reset` in this case as it doesn't look like OP is using nested lists, `li { list-style-type:decimal; }` should be enough. Anyway, nice answer :)

Comment: I would tend to agree with you @Morpheus, I'm going to assume the OP was requesting it for some layout/design reason (whether necessary or not).

Answer (score 2):

You can check this out,
[https://fiddle.jshell.net/RemyaJ/af7tcL0m/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/RemyaJ/j260vxzb/)

Use counter increment css,

```
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

label:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is styling the number and lining up the answer paragraph.  It might be easier to just remove the number on the ordered list and use a [counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) applying it to the `.question` element.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: qa;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  counter-increment: qa;
  padding: 1em;
}

li .question, li .answer {
  display: block;
}

li .question {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

li .question:before {
  content: counter(qa)". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Example answer</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @Seano That's odd.  I didn't even see his answer.  Must have needed to hit the load more answers button and just didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some negative margin on `.answer` element and also `display: block`.

```css
hr {
  margin: 15px 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.answer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum non adipisci saepe dicta quasi, dolor, facilis provident voluptate eius quod facere et impedit obcaecati enim. Delectus, nihil laudantium magni ad!</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
    <hr>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="question">Example question</span>
    <span class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, voluptatum, molestiae. Magnam fuga quibusdam saepe animi dolore aperiam labore iusto, aspernatur esse, distinctio voluptas doloribus quasi rerum! Consectetur, quos quidem.</span>
    <a class="expand-collapse-button" href="#"></a>
    <hr>
  </li>
</ol>
```